# How to move buttons text when state is pressed

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I made a custom background for a button and also for different button states. But now I made to a point that I cannot understand.

When button is in normal state then it looks just fine. But when I press the button, I need to move text down few pixels because button background image moving (actually it feels like it moving on the image, because first there's border under the button and when it's in pressed state then this border disappears). Please see image below.

How can I move the buttons text in the button when buttons state is pressed? (maybe padding somehow or layout custom for a button)

[image]

Comment: you may try this for 3D button http://stackoverflow.com/a/19248175/2149195

Comment: Addendum to the bounty: I'd now tried a bunch of stuff with 9 patches to get the text content to move. The most promising of which looked like `android:variablePadding="true"` but I'm still having no luck (and yea, I tried invalidating the view on touch events....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not try it myself but if you use nine-patch as a background drawable for both states then you should consider setting proper padding box in pressed state drawable. See details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Comment: Do I have to set more top padding to a pressed 9-patch?

Comment: I would say yes. And bottom padding box part should be moved rightwards.

Comment: I think this is the best approach, doing this in code is painful way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm adjusting the content are by the same distances as the button area moves but The text never moves, the button is just stretched larger so that the text satisfies both the pressed and unpressed states simultaneously.

Answer (score 6):

Setting padding in 9-patch didn't work for me. 
Setting padding in touch listeners is messy, would litter code anywhere buttons are used.

I went with subclassing `Button`, and it turned out reasonably tidy. In my case, I wanted to offset icon (`drawableLeft`) and text 1px left and 1px down.

Subclassed button widget:

```
package com.myapp.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.myapp.R;

public class OffsetButton extends Button {

    public OffsetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public OffsetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public OffsetButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean value = super.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_normal);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_pressed);
            setPadding(getPaddingLeft() + 1, getPaddingTop() + 1, getPaddingRight() - 1,
                    getPaddingBottom() - 1);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

And use it in layout like this:

```
<com.myapp.widgets.OffsetButton
    android:text="@string/click_me"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_will_be_offset_too_thats_good" />
```

Few notes:

- I *did not* use `StateListDrawable` for background, and am instead switching backgrounds in code. When I tried using `StateListDrawable`, there would be small pause between padding change and background change. That didn't look good.
- Setting background resets padding, so don't need to adjust padding in `ACTION_UP` case
- It was important to increase top and left padding, and *at the same time decrease* bottom and right padding. So the size of content area stays the same and content area is effectively just shifted.

Comment: Feels very tidy solution indeed. Will try it out. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use padding on the view. You can add an OnTouchListener to the button or view like

```
viewF.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
        if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { 
            //set your padding            
        } else if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //set your padding            
        }   
        return true; 
    } 
});
```

The ontouchlistener will let your know when the button is pressed and not.

Comment: As i said in previous answer. Not `ontouchlistener` nor a `gesture` nor anything can give you the button `pressed`. If the button is scrolled you will get the padding that you had set in `ACTION_DOWN`. You dont even get the `ACTION_UP` event any more to change the padding to the default value. 24k reputation and answer like that. It is a shame. I am not downvoting because i am on a good mood.

Answer (score 1):

The Pēteris Caune answer works worse than overriding setPressed(). But everithing OK with setPressed until you test your app at ICS or lower device and add button as listview item. 
To archieve this I've improved my button's class:

```
public class OffsetButton extends Button {

    private static final int OFFSET_IN_DP = 6;
    private int offset_in_px;
    private boolean wasPressed = false;
    private Integer[] defaultPaddings;

    public OffsetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    public OffsetButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public OffsetButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        offset_in_px = (int) DisplayUtil.convertDpToPixel(OFFSET_IN_DP);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        if (pressed && !wasPressed) {
            changePaddings();
        }
        if (!pressed && wasPressed) {
            resetPaddings();
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }

    private void changePaddings() {
        defaultPaddings = new Integer[]{getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom()};
        setPadding(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() + offset_in_px, getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom() - offset_in_px);
        wasPressed = true;
    }

    private void resetPaddings() {
        setPadding(defaultPaddings[0], defaultPaddings[1], defaultPaddings[2], defaultPaddings[3]);
        wasPressed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        resetPaddings();
        return super.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (isEnabled())
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !wasPressed) {
                changePaddings();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && wasPressed) {
                resetPaddings();
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this when I have two buttons side by side in a linearlayout. even though the same amount of padding is being added as is being removed, the button height is changing during a press causing the linearlayout to change height

Comment: I fixed the above my using baselineAligned=false for my LinearLayout. It might be worth checking for enabled in the onTouchEvent.

Answer (score 0):

this might just work:

```
setPadding(left, top, right, bottom); // Normal
setPadding(left, top + x, right, bottom - x); // Pressed
```

Comment: @LASVEGAS How can I detect when button is in pressed state?

Comment: I guess you need to add View.OnTouchListener & listen for MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Comment: *...& listen for MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN*. Its not so easy as you say. For a stationary button its ok. But what happens when the button is scrolled. `ACTION_DOWN` is **NOT** the same as the `pressed state = true` in xml selector. There is **not** an event for `pressed state` that you can catch and do your thing.