# How to shift text on a button which is currently pressed?

Tags: android

I want to shift a little bit the text on the button that is currently pressed. In my case the button has custom background and the button will look much better if the text will be shifted.

I made two NinePath images with different paddings:

[image]

[image]

And set them using a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn"/>

</selector>
```

This doesn't work, the text remains on its position when the button is pressed (and the background is swapped).

Are my NinePath images OK? Is there any way to shift the text without setting touch listeners?

P.S. Same question was asked already but the "answer" is exactly the solution I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7677098/694770

Answer (score 1):

Your 9-patch images look good. That said, I came across this question because I had exactly the same problem, and my images didn't work either.

I ended up subclassing `Button` and messing with padding. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748170/5821)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:text="Pressed state text" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:text="Default text"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: It causes an exception, because you have to specify the drawable.  But even if it is defined the text is not changing. I think selector works only for the drawable.