# How to create custom button with xml style

Tags: android

[image]

Please suggest someone how to create button like this with xml style in android, without using any image only with the help of color ,shape and style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `layer-list` for this.Try the below code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />
```

button_background.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#A9A9A9"
        android:type="linear" />


            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#5E2612" />


            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="#A9A9A9"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:type="linear" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />


        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

It should work

[image]

Comment: it now working please suggest me how to do like mentioned image

Comment: This style is almost same as your desired image.Let me know what more you want?

Answer (score 3):

Check out these examples how to create custum buttons. 
[Link1](http://undertowsam.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/design-custom-background-and-button-for-android-using-xml/)
[Link2](http://www.thesecretpie.com/2010/07/creating-custom-fancy-buttons-in.html)