# Move text on pressed button

Tags: android

I have a button and while it is in non-pressed state looks OK but as soon as I press it I'd like to move the text to the right and bottom. I want to achieve 3D effect of pressing button visually.

So, I guess question is: How can I move the text in the button only when button is pressed?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move buttons text when state is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676986/how-to-move-buttons-text-when-state-is-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example leave the text in the button empty and use a transparent textView on top of the button and animate the textView to the right and the bottom on click.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try that!